# Group variables into vectors by grouping variable

Tags: r, recode

I have a dataset containing the access logs of a website. Every step within the website is a line in the data. Now I want the pages visited by the user, grouped by session id into a vector (and these pages as character variables). This is necessary to user the ClickStream package. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Thanks in advance!

[image: The data on top is how it is, and below how I want it to be]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Do I do it in the same way as the other when I want to have the vectors ordered by the time value?